# Trying to determine a link with specific nodes

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to call upon an existing link but with specific nodes. keep in mind this command is inside a foreach. So for now I have this:

```
foreach max-links
[
the-links -> ask the-links
show [label] of [one-of my-out-links] of [end2] of the-links with [other-end = [end1] of the-links]
]
```

the "with" command doesn't work because it expects an agent set. I also tried this with the "and" command which doesn't work because it requires a true or false.
Can someone please tell me how to add the:

> [other-end = [end1] of the-links]

section to the code?

Answer (score 2):

here is your code with slightly different spacing

```
foreach max-links
[ the-links ->
  ask the-links
  show [label] of [one-of my-out-links] of [end2] of the-links with [other-end = [end1] of the-links]
]
```

Problem 1: you need to have brackets around what the 'the-links' is being asked to do

Problem 2: You have much too much convoluted logic in one line of code - there are no brackets to help. If you want to debug, break it into several steps and then combine only when it works. Also, I suspect 'the-links' is a single link (since it's in a `foreach`) rather than a link-set so you should give it a singular name to help keep your thinking clear.

So: `show [label] of [one-of my-out-links] of [end2] of the-links with [other-end = [end1] of the-links]`

Becomes

```
let chosen-turtle [end2] of the-link with [other-end = [end1] of the-link]
let chosen-link [one-of my-out-links] of chosen-turtle
show [label] of chosen-turtle
```

Having broken it into steps like this, it is clear that the first line makes no sense. If the `other-end` of the-link is `[end1] of the-link` then you are simply asking for `[end2] of the-link`.

Having spotted the (likely) problem, the fixed code is:

```
foreach max-links
[ the-link ->
  ask the-link
  [ let chosen-turtle [end2] of the-link
    let chosen-link [one-of my-out-links] of chosen-turtle
    show [label] of chosen-turtle
  ]
]
```

And, if that works (I can't test it) then you can put it back into one line if you like. But start it in multiple lines because NetLogo will point to the line with the problem, making it easier to debug.

```
foreach max-links
[ the-link ->
  ask the-link
  [ show [label] of [one-of my-out-links] of [end2] of the-link
  ]
]
```